# How to use check-expect in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to use the check-expect function in scheme but I keep being told its an unbound identifier for check-expect. Isn't check-expect a function I can use already? Below is my code:

```
#lang racket

(define contains (lambda (item list*) 
                   (if (equal? list* '()) 
                        #f
                        (if (equal? item (car list*)) 
                            #t
                            (contains item (cdr list*))))))

(define z (list 1 2 3))
(define q (list 4 5 6))
(define p (list "apple" "orange" "carrot"))
(check-expect (contains 1 z) #t)
```

Answer (score 12):

Old question, but answer for the googlers:

You can `(require test-engine/racket-tests)`, which [defines `check-expect`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/test-engine/index.html?q=#%28form._%28%28lib._test-engine%2Fracket-tests..rkt%29._check-expect%29%29).

Note that, unlike BSL, you'll have to run the tests with [`(test)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/test-engine/index.html?q=#%28form._%28%28lib._test-engine%2Fracket-tests..rkt%29._test%29%29).

Answer (score 6):

`check-expect` is not technically built into scheme or Racket automatically.

Note that you are using `#lang racket`.  That is the professional Racket language, and that language expects you to know and state explicitly what libraries to import.  It will not auto-import them for you.

(Now, you could require a [unit testing library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/index.html); there is one that comes with the Racket standard library.)

But if you are just starting to learn programming, it makes much more sense to use one of the [teaching languages](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/index.html) within Racket.

For the code you're using above, I suspect you'll probably want this instead.  Start DrRacket and choose "Beginner Student Language" from the "How to Design Programs" submenu in the "Language" menu.

See http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/prologue.html for more details.

Comment: No possibility to write the requirements directly in the code so I make the file machine-independent (the solution with the menu works only on the current computer)? Something like `(require lang/htdp-beginner)` or `#lang 2htdp/bsl` ?

Comment: @Liviu I added an answer just now that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to come up with this workaround:

At the top of the file (but after `#lang racket`) added a line

`(require rackunit)`

Instead of `(check-expect)` I've used

`(check-equal?   (member? "a" (list "b" "a")) #f )`

Unlike in `check-expect`, tests must be added *after* the function definitions. 
If the checks are successful, there is *no output*. Only when a tests fails,  the output looks like this:

```
--------------------
FAILURE
name:       check-equal?
actual:     #f
expected:   #t
expression: (check-equal? #f (member? "a" (list "b" "a")))
message:    "test"
```

More Info: [RackUnit documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html#%28part._.Shortcuts_for_.Defining_.Test_.Cases%29)

Answer (score 0):

I took a class using DrRacket and looked at the first assignment in Terminal (Mac).

The line in this file, automatically added by DrRacket, which made check-expect available is:

```
#reader(lib "htdp-beginner-reader.ss" "lang")((modname basic) (read-case-sensitive #t) (teachpacks ()) (htdp-settings #(#t constructor repeating-decimal #f #t none #f () #f)))
```

As a side note, I wanted to try a Racket program without DrRacket. Just to test, I decided to do `(+ 1 2)`. To get it to work, my file looks like this:

```
#! /Applications/Racket\ v6.2.1/bin/racket
#lang racket
(+ 1 2)
```

I run it in Terminal like this:

```
racket test.rkt
```

I put this in .bash_profile:

```
alias racket='/Applications/Racket\ v6.2.1/bin/racket'
```